# Python list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, range, out

I keep getting an IndexError: list assignment index out of range.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import asciidata

fv = [] 
fb = []
data = asciidata.open('Flux.txt')
for i in data[1]:
    fv.append(float(i))
for i in data[2]:
    fb.append(float(i))

mv = []
mb = []
for i in range (0,25):
    mv[i] = 10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(fv[i]/1220000)
    mb[i] = 11.0 - 2.5 * np.log(fb[i]/339368)
    print i, mv[i], mb[i]
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\StevenScripts\Opdracht 1 PS\Flux.py", line 15, in <module>

    mv[i] = 10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(fv[i]/1220000)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add that kind of information.

Answer (score 6):

```
mv.append(10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(fv[i]/1220000))
mb.append(11.0 - 2.5 * np.log(fb[i]/339368))
```

mv[i] wont work because there is no ith index

really I would use a list comprehension

```
mv = [10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(val/1220000) for val in fv]
```

and since you are using numpy you can do even better

```
fv = np.array(fv)
mv = 10 - np.log(fv/1220000)*2.5
```